# Methods for geographic distance search in MySQL

Tags: mysql, gis, mysql-5.6

I'm looking for the fasted way to search for Points that are within a certain distance from another given Point. I have a MyISAM table with Points spatially indexed representing geographic locations (latitude, longitude).

If MySQL supported it, I think [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) would do the job. But it doesn't, so I got the following expression that uses a buffer to generate a circle and then look for points that fall within this circle :

```
ST_Within(geopoint, ST_Buffer(Point(@lat, @lng), @radius))
```

It seems to be working fine and I believe it uses the index. But is it a good enough solution? How precise is ST_Within and ST_Buffer for geography purposes?

**UPDATE:** I concluded that MySQL doesn't offer support for Geography coordinates and that all operations are done on a Euclidean plane (even if you specify the SRID). Depending on the location, that eventually leads to big imprecisions. So the coordinates need to be transformed prior to using MySQL Spatial functions.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of spatial/geographic stuff upgrading to Postgres/PostGIS might be a better option in the long run (instead of creating a workaround each time you find a missing feature).

Answer (score 3):

We do something similar to this at work.

We get about 1 million queries per hour and when we were using spatial indexes, it would basically take the database down and queries would get put in a pending state. Some queries were pending for about `8,000` seconds (about 2 hours). So we had to find another way, and this was the best that we could come up with, it now no longer backs up the database, and returns results in milliseconds.

What we do is first we have a distance function which looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `distance`(`lat1` DECIMAL(10,7), `lon1` DECIMAL(10,7), `lat2` DECIMAL(10,7), `lon2` DECIMAL(10,7)) RETURNS double
BEGIN
    DECLARE X DOUBLE;
    DECLARE PI DECIMAL(21, 20);
    SET PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
    SET X  = SIN(lat1 * PI / 180)
    * SIN(lat2 * PI / 180)
    + COS(lat1 * PI / 180)
    * COS(lat2 * PI / 180)
    * COS((lon2 * PI / 180) - (lon1 * PI / 180));
    SET X = ATAN((SQRT( 1- POWER( X, 2))) / X);
    RETURN (1.852 * 60.0 * ((X / PI) * 180)) / 1.609344;
END
```

Remove `/ 1.609344` on the return line to get kilometers

We then have a procedure to calculate the distance between your location and the surrounding area. From what we tested this was the fastest (simplified version of what we have):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `MyRadius`(IN `p_lat` DOUBLE, IN `p_long` DOUBLE, IN `radius` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    SELECT distance(p_lat, p_long, g.latitude, g.longitude) as distance, country, region, city
    from geocity g
    having distance <= radius
    order by distance asc limit 100;
END
```

You may want to change the `order` clause, because I am not sure how you want to order it.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that it doesn't take advantage of indexes so it can be really slow on big databases!

Comment: Our database uses 3 tables each has a minimum of 1,000,000 records in it, and it does take advantage of an index. We have an index on `latitude` and `longitude`